# How do I always show the user picker with Google OAuth 2.0 flow, but not force approval?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

In a browser with no Google users logged in yet, when I redirect to Google to authenticate (OAuth 2.0 workflow), first Google asks me to log in, asks for permission, the redirects back to my site. That works great.

The next time I go through that workflow, it looks at my one logged-in Google user, and because I already gave permission, it doesn't show any Google page but rather redirects right back to my site.

But what if I'd like to log in as another Google user? It doesn't give me an opportunity to do that. My ideal behavior is it a) shows the user picker every time b) if the selected user has already granted access, don't ask for access again.

I know there's the argument *approval_prompt: force* which satisfies (a) but not (b), i.e. it shows the picker but asks for approval again. So that's not ideal. I also tried to see if setting *login_prompt* to some bogus value would do the trick, but no luck.

I'm looking at this documentation for Google's OAuth2.0 arguments and values:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Added *prompt: 'select_account'*

Details here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect